# Ky Fan's inequality about the eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The inequality says:
Any matrices $X$ and $Y$ in $\mathcal{S}^n$ satisfy the inequality
$$\left\| X - Y \right\| \geq \left\| \lambda(X) - \lambda(Y) \right\|,$$
where the equality holds if and only if $X$ and $Y$ have a simultaneous ordered spectral decomposition, i.e., there exists an orthogonal matrix $U$ such that
$$Y = U \Lambda(Y) U^T, \quad X = U \Lambda(X)U^T.$$
I am confused about the only if part. How to prove this theorem (only if part)?

Norm is the frobenius norm and $\Lambda(X) = \mathrm{Diag} (\lambda(X))$ is the eigenvalues.

Comment: What (matrix?) norm are you applying here?  Is $\lambda(X)$ the same as $\Lambda(X)$?

Comment: it is frobenius norm, $\Lambda(X)= \text{Diag}(\lambda(X))$